Nuxt.js axios send big data from Laravel back
I have this problem, I have Nuxt and axios, I need to send files about 100mb+. When sending Nuxt, new FormData() is generated and this generation takes a very very long time to load.
jurnals: [],
    formData: {
      year: null,
      title: null,
      jurnal: null,
      image: null,
    },
    paginate: {},
    response: null,
    formType: null,
    isOpenModal: false,
    isLoading: false,


    store() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const sendFormData = new FormData();
      for (const key in this.formData) {
        sendFormData.append(key, this.formData[key]);
      }

//Loading ... is 5,3,4 min and send request 
      axios
        .post(`${api}/jurnals`, sendFormData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.response = res;
          // Обработка ответа
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.formData = {
            year: null,
            title: null,
            jurnal: null,
            image: null,
          };
          this.isOpenModal = false;
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    },

 const sendFormData = new FormData();
   for (const key in this.formData) {
         sendFormData.append(key, this.formData[key]); // jurenal 60mb more loading whY?
       }

I don’t really know why, but it takes me a long time to do it.
If the size is large than the download and the request to Laravel is processed quickly.

Have you done any logging on the server side to see where it is getting stuck?

Have you looked in you browser debug toolbar to see if anything is awry there?
